# Can a remote node know my wallet address?

Tags: security, privacy, remote-access

When I connect my wallet to a remote node, does it know my wallet address?

What information about a connecting wallet is revealed to the remote node?

Answer (score 3):

No.
The only leaked data is your IP to the first node as you connect to it. This can however be prevented by the use of VPNs or Kovri once available.

Comment: Don't forget to mention Tor / torsocks which is better than using a VPN: https://github.com/monero-project/monero#using-tor